# Delphi ListView String in Bold

Tags: delphi

I am trying to get some text to appear in Bold.

Here is the code:

```
if (mfDeleted in flags) then
      begin
         //Font.Style:=[fsBold]; //This is just changing all to bold not just this row
         s := s + 'Deleted,'; //I need this Deleted string or whole row to be bold.
      end;
```

How can I do this?

Note: See comments in code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to handle `OnAdvancedCustomDrawItem` and `OnAdvancedCustomDrawSubItem`. Like this:

```
procedure TMyForm.ListViewAdvancedCustomDrawItem(Sender: TCustomListView; 
  Item: TListItem; State: TCustomDrawState; Stage: TCustomDrawStage; 
  var DefaultDraw: Boolean);
begin
  Sender.Canvas.Font.Style := [fsBold];
end;

procedure TMyForm.ListViewAdvancedCustomDrawSubItem(Sender: TCustomListView; 
  Item: TListItem; SubItem: Integer; State: TCustomDrawState; 
  Stage: TCustomDrawStage; var DefaultDraw: Boolean);
begin
  Sender.Canvas.Font.Style := [fsBold];
end;
```

Obviously you need to hook these event handlers up to the appropriate events. And you'll need to add some logic to ensure that you only do this for rows/columns that you intend to highlight.